# Using LINQ to group together a list of nodes and a list of their attributes

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with a list of Nodes (with properties ID and Name), and a second table with a list of Node Attributes (with a reference Parent to the corresponding Node ID). I usually query for the node, and then get its attributes, to populate an object

```
public class NodeWithAttributes
 {
     public Node Node = new Node();
     public List<NodeAttribute> NodeAttributes = new List<NodeAttribute>();
 }
```

However, when I want to query for a list of 'NodeWithAttributes' things get complicated. I'm trying to group the attributes together by Parent, and then assigning them to the object - something like :

```
var results = (from n in dbNodes.Nodes
                join na in dbNodes.NodeAttributes on n.ID equals na.Parent
                group na by na.Parent
                into g
                select new NodeWithAttributes
                {
                    Node = n,
                    NodeAttributes = g
                }                                                              
                ).ToList();
```

But I can only seem to return the group, and not an object based on it. What can I do to return a List of NodeWithAttributes?

Comment: I don't think you can use `n` after using `into`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm finding. Can I group into an object to include n?

Comment: No, not really (but I very much appreciate it!). I still can't get a List of Nodes, each with its own List of NodeAttributes, from a single query - which is what I'd ideally want.

Comment: The query that I wrote should give you results. Replace Customer with Node and Orders with NodeAttributes

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case no need to group by data.  If you want Parent Children try to use query similar to following.

```
   var query = from c in north.Customers   
               orderby c.CustomerID
               select new
               {
                  customer = c,
                  orders = c.Orders
               };


        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.customer.CompanyName);
            foreach (var ord in item.orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ord.OrderDate + " " + ord.OrderID);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```